# Facebook rejected app from App Review

Tags: facebook

In my iOS app, I have used `FacebookSDK` and sharing features. For that I have included permission for `publish_actions` at login time. As per `Facebook` guideline you have to submit your app for review if you are using `FacebookSDK`.

So I have submitted my application for `Facebook` review along with simulator build, some descriptions, screencast (video or images) for how app is posted on `Facebook`. But `Facebook` rejects my app and I can’t identify reason.

It shows reason is **cant get item 1 of {}**. Any one have any idea why build is rejected and how `Facebook` review apps.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it's about Facebook policy, not coding.

Comment: @JoshCaswell The question is surely about Facebook, but it is looking for solution that if anything is missing in code or any special procedure have to follow while uploading on Facebook review. It is not only related to`Facebook`, it is related to developer who is facing issue.

Comment: And this community is for when you are developing something and facing some hurdles, then you can ask for solution here.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue, when I have uploaded app for `Facebook` review it rejected two times. Here are couple of things you should look on them :

1. Login on [Facebook for Developers](https://developers.facebook.com)
2. Go to App Review from left panel
3. From above screen shot click on first edit notes

   1. Check respective check box as per your requirements.
   2. Select one option from radio buttons  as per your requirements.
   3. Add step by step description of `How your app use FacebookSDK` here also include credentials (Facebook username and password which does not used before) for testing.
   4. At last upload video as screencast (Your application video how it works with Facebook and you have to show how it look on your timeline on [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com))
   5. Click on Save.
4. Now from above screen shot click on second edit notes

   1. Add test user if you want to add.
   2. Select different build, upload build (which built with simulator) there and save.
5. Now hit on `Submit For Review`

Then also if any case you get rejected, Click on Green `Have Question` button. Add manager as your app name and select, then ask question to support team that what is the problem with your build and what is reason for reject. They will reply and you will find solution.

Comment: Hi @VRAwesome did you successfully manage to get an app passed review?

Comment: thanks for your reply. Yeah we are experiencing the same problem, specifically with the screencast. They say they can't see "how the use of this permission directly improves the user experience in your app", but I'm struggling to find anyone else who is experiencing the same thing. Have you got any basic tips for the screencast? We are on submission 4 and still nothing - any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks